# Error `undefined method `state' for "AK":String` for `collection_select`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After adding the second method, `uniq.pluck(:state)` to the code below, I'm getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `state' for "AK":String.
```

I looked at all the posts on here and couldn't find anything related to this problem. Any insights or help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%= f.collection_select :state, (Boli.order(:state).uniq.pluck(:state)), :id, :state, include_blank: true %>
```

Thank you @D-side, now having difficulties using grouped_collection.  I'd like the user to be able to select a group of banks in a particular state.  Getting the error message undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol, using the following code:

```
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select :bank, :id, Boli.order(:bank), :id, :bank, include_blank: true%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pluck` with a single attribute name returns an array of attribute values. Strings, in your case.

`collection_select`, however, is built with model instances in mind, in that it accepts... well, [the docs say it better](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) anyway:

> #### collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
>
> <...>
>
> The `:value_method` and `:text_method` parameters are methods to be called on each member of collection. The return values are used as the value attribute and contents of each `<option>` tag, respectively. They can also be any object that responds to call, such as a proc, that will be called for each member of the collection to retrieve the value/text.

Obviously, since you've already fetched values of the attribute `state`, calling `state` on the resulting values once more is nonsensical.

You can fix this in multiple ways.

#### PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON (expr)`

By replacing `.uniq.pluck(:state)` with `.select("DISTINCT ON (state) id, state")` you'll get ActiveRecord model instances, so every element of the resulting collection will have methods `id` and `state`, as `collection_select` expects.

#### Or use the query you have, with `pluck`

...by giving `proc`s instead of `:id` and `:state` that take a string as an argument and produce appropriate values.

It all boils down to what you need.

Comment: thank you @d-side that works perfectly!  I did have to change my local database from sqlite to postgreSQL, other than that it worked like a charm.

Comment: does the link you provided work with form builders too?  It seems it's addressing situations without form builders.  I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown box arrangement and using grouped_collection and am having problems with that now too.  See code above.

Comment: @richiepop2 docs for the form builders reference these, so I thought I'd save the readers an extra roundtrip. You can see the argument signature doesn't match, yes, but everything stil applies.